# Is this a proper CDF?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a function that is

$$F_X(x) \in (0, 1]~~\text{for}~~0 < x_0 < x$$
and
$$F_X(x) = 0~~\text{for}~~0 < x \leq x_0.$$

For $x > x_0$, $F(x)$ follows the properties of the CDF (e.g., right-continuous and non-decresing). Does $F(x)$ exist as a proper CDF at or below $x_0$? I am also unsure how to check whether $F(x)$ is right-continuous at $x_0$ or not.

Comment: $F_X(x) = (0,1]$ doesn't make sense to me. Can you explain?

Comment: Edited. Thanks for pointing out. It should be $F_X(x) \in (0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order that $F$ be right-continuous at $x_0,$ you need $\lim\limits_{x\,\downarrow\, x_0} F(x) = F(x_0).$ I.e. $x$ approaches $x_0$ from the right. You've decided that $F(x_0)=0,$ so you need $\lim\limits_{x\,\downarrow\,x_0} F(x) = 0.$  Whether that is true depends on what $F(x)$ is for values of $x$ that are greater than $x_0.$ And you have not told us what those are.

Comment: Unfortunately, the exact expression of $F(x)$ is unknown for $x > x_0$.